# How to establish temporary remote connection between two hosts both behind router

Tags: ssh, router, remote-access

The scenario is as follows:

NOVICE == PC_A (192.168.0.X) <-> Router_A <-> Internet <-> Router_B <-> PC_B(192.168.1.X) == ME

I need access to PC_B in order to access not only PC_B but also other (network) resources. Best would be SSH.

- I don't have administrative access to both routers (e.g. for port forwarding).
- I don't have an account on PC_B.
- As the user on PC_B is not very familiar with installation and configuration of computers I want to keep the effort for him very low.
- PC_B may be both Windows and Linux systems.
- PC_A is on Linux

Is there a simple way for the owner of PC_A to temporary allow me access to its computer to help him? Afterwards when all is set and done, I need to be sure that all is disabled and no one may abuse the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) might be a good choice.
Free for non-commercial use, supports windows&linux,  runs without installation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it is a bit overblown, I don't need remote audio/video as well as session appointments and video capture. Additionally I need to trust the manufacture, but if no other software or solution come up I will try it.